# Temporary block from yahoo

Tags: postfix-mta, yahoo, dkim, yahoo-mail

For quite some time we have been getting the following error from yahoo:

```
mail.log:6452:Apr 22 19:21:06 aegir postfix/smtp[8997]: 87BCF4C93F: host mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.228.110] said: 421 4.7.0 [IPTS04] Messages from 188.93.125.68 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

If someone did get the similar, how did you solve this issue?
I've been trying to contact Yahoo but everytime I get automated response and ticket closure as I send it.

What other thing I can offer is DMARC report if its relevant:
https://mxtoolbox.com/DmarcReportAnalyzer.aspx?id=F-9a3a8364-6cba-41f9-b93f-cfc32155a3f6

Test for headers and every check seems to be working alright:
https://www.mail-tester.com/test-m5ytebosm

Google email is showing everything is pass:

[gmail email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0JFe.png)

[gmail header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkn7x.png)

For now I've tried changing OpenDKIM to relaxed/relaxed from relaxed/simple.

Removed p=quarantine and added p=none

Sorted out SPF record for official signing domain just in case, added another IP address where resourcecenter is found.

Will provide additional info if needed.